# Enviar la subclase como argumento en el super constructor

Tags: java, herencia, constructor

Si una clase en su constructor llama `super(/*argumentos*/);` ¿cómo hago que se envie a sí misma? (Asi misma como parametro, ¿de que otra forma podria enviarse? y obcio que la subclase, la superclase no puede llamar a `super();` (al menos no en mi ejemplo))

```
public abstract class Parent {
Otro objeto;
public Parent (String variableNoImportante) {
objeto = new Otro(variableNoImportante,VARIABLEOBJETOHIJO);}}
```

Aqui tiene que enviar al objeto que lo llama, si es una instancia de Child o si es cualquier otra subclase lo que envia como parametro es el objeto que invoca `super(str);`.

```
public class Child extends Parent {
public Child(String variableNoImportante) {
super(variableNoImportante);
}}
public class Otro {
public Otro(String varNoImp,Parent objChild) {
/*do something*/}}
```

El problema es que cuando en el tercer objeto ocupo `objChild.variables`, me da las variables por defecto que creé para el `Parent` en lugar de las sobrescritas por `Child`. Obvio, porque uso this.

Si lo remplazo por: `super(variableNoImportante,this);` y `public Parent(String varNoImp,Child hijo) {objeto = new Otro(varNoImp,hijo);}` entonces me dice que no puedo usar `this` en un constructor.

¿Alguna sugerencia? Incluso no sé por qué me regresa los parámetros de `Parent` si es abstracta.
(No entiendo por qué se complican tanto, no importa que es lo que quiero lograr, esto es un ejemplo general, porque esta es una comunidad, si pongo tal cual mi proyecto entonces ya no podria ayudar a alguien más, solo a mi)
(la herencia es precisamente por que así puedo ocupar el mismo constructor para todas las clases.)
No puedo crear otro objeto Child por que entonces para que lo cree antes, si lo hago se haria un bucle: el constructor de Child llama al constructor de Parent que crea un nuevo Child.
Ademas obviamente hay mas cosas en el constructor de Child y mas parametros, si pongo un nuevo Child (valga la redundancia) se crea uno nuevo sin parametros ¿y los del otro donde quedan? Tambien si, Child no es la unica subclase que tiene Parent.
¿Acaso no hay una forma de evitar que se sobrescriba el constructor?

Comment: exactamente qué quieres lograr? , a lo mejor te estás yendo por la vía errónea.

Comment: Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que esten enlazadas todas las piezas de un todo, por ejemplo: creo una pierna  de caballo y se a que caballo pertenece.

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo mas claro ?

Comment: A ese se le llama composición, pero aún no respondes la pregunta en sí, qué quieres lograr, porque no veo el sentido de usar herencia.

Comment: Decir "¿cómo hago que se envie a sí misma?" , es demasiado ambigüo , pasar qué? la instancia hija?, la clase?, paramétros?, métodos?

Comment: Me parece que tienes un problema de cómo implementar algo, intentas implementarlo con clases y subclases y luego en tu búsqueda de solución te sale este problema de diseño de clases. Sería muy bueno si pudieses indicar cuál es el problema original, cuál es la propuesta de diseño que tienes y qué problema tienes con eso. De momento, te digo que lo que pones en la pregunta se considera un code smell.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, no tengo un problema para implementar, ni se a que te refieres con diseño de clases, lo que pasa es que no se expresar el real sentido de las cosas. Mi problema original es que Java me obliga a sobre escribir en cada subclase el constructor, y yo diseñe el constructor exactamente como lo necesito para todas mis subclases. Vuelvo a que no se a que te refieres con diseño, Y tampoco se que es code smell, ¿Huele a codigo?

Comment: *Mi problema original es que Java me obliga a sobre escribir en cada subclase el constructor, y yo diseñe el constructor exactamente como lo necesito para todas mis subclases* yo creo que no. Lo que tienes ahorita (el diseño de tus clases) es complicado puesto que el padre debe conocer a sus hijos (pueden haber varios, no solo uno) y saber cómo llamar a dichos constructores (eso es un code smell, es decir que el código tiene problemas). Puedo recomendar dos alternativas: 1) La clase `Otro` recibe como argumento una clase `Parent` y así puedes usar mejor la relación entre `Otro` y `Parent`.

Comment: De esa manera `Parent` es más abstracto y puro. Alternativa 2) Tener una clase que se encargue de vincular a `Parent` (y sus hijos) con la instancia de `Otro`.